# How to receive sms in twilio trial account number

Tags: twilio, sms-gateway

I am trying to send sms for twilio trial account in java and i am not able to send the sms to my twilio account eventhough i have succeed in sending the sms from twillo account.Thanks for the help .

Comment: Hi! Could you include some of your code?

Comment: you can't - you need to buy a real number - not the trial